# Nodejs/npm: How to reinstall/recompile copied app packages

Tags: node.js, package, npm, offline, reinstall

**Setup:**

- A VM with an Internet connection where `npm install` will be executed to install all the app dependencies. The result will be a folder with the app and its dependencies in `node_modules`.
- Between the app modules is fi: `mongoose`, which on installation time uses `node-gyp` to compile a native BSON extension.
- The app folder is copied to another VM without an Internet conection and it is fully functional, but then the compiled extensions don't work but its `.js` fallbacks does.

**Question:**

How can I reinstall/recompile/regenerate all the app modules on the new VM without an Internet conection?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is precisely what the [npm rebuild](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-rebuild.html) command does. Just run `npm rebuild` inside your app directory after it is copied over to the new VM and any binary add-ons will be recompiled to match the current CPU architecture and node version. If the initial `npm install` before the copy was completely successful, the `npm rebuild` on the second VM will not need to download anything. Just make sure the second VM has a reasonably-close version of node and the appropriate lower level compilers, libraries, etc (build-essential and python on debian, for example).